# C# name doesnt exist in current context

Tags: c#

Below is my main code the following code block is my book class. I am fairly new to c# and haven't encountered this error before. I am getting errors on line 39 and 48. Both are the `printInformation()` calls. The error is

> the name 'printInformation' does not exist in the current context

I'm not sure what to do, I tried putting all the code from both the book class and the main class into a seperate file where all the code was together and it doesn't give an error.

Does this means there is something I need to do as far as the public and private classes used or is it something else. I have public getters and setters for the values `title`, `author`, `price`, and `isbn`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of books you have, followed by the number 1 or number 2 seperated by a space");
            Console.Write("Enter 1 if you would like to sort the books by price in ascending order");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 if you would like to sort the books by title alphabetically.");
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numberArray = number.Split(' ');
            List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();

            // for the number entered input values
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(numberArray[0]); i++)
            {
                bookList.Add(new Book
                {
                    Title = Console.ReadLine(),
                    Author = Console.ReadLine(),
                    Price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()),
                    ISBN = Console.ReadLine()
                });
            }
            // sorting based on condition given
            if (Convert.ToInt16(numberArray[1]) == 1)
            {
                var sortedList = from book in bookList orderby book.Price select book;

                foreach (var book in sortedList)
                {
                    printInformation(book.Title, book.Author, book.Price, book.ISBN);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var sortedList = from book in bookList orderby book.Title select book;

                foreach (var book in sortedList)
                {
                    printInformation(book.Title, book.Author, book.Price, book.ISBN);
                }
            }

            // added this to hold the console window
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Book class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Book
    {
        // private fields
        private string title;
        private string author;
        private double price;
        private string isbn;

        public static void printInformation(string _title, string _author, double _price, string _isbn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_title + " written by " + _author + " is " + _price.ToString() + " dollars, with ISBN " + _isbn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have private fields, and a static method. Why do your parameter names start with an underscore (and potentially your fields do not?). As it stands why have `printInformation` as part of your Book class? There are some things you could think about (the answers to solve your problem were given already, but there are quite some things that can be improved in your code as well, which will probably not be addressed)

Answer (score 1):

`printInformation` method is declared in the `Book` class as `static`, so you need to call it specifying the type name:

```
Book.printInformation(book.Title, book.Author, book.Price, book.ISBN);
```

Btw, you don't need this method, if you want to a string representation of a `Book`, a better way is to override `ToString` method in the `Book` class.